# Alter Services JSON Response

Tags: 7, views, services

I have created a view to render all taxonomy terms and displayed it through a service. I have also created an endpoint in the service module to hit the url through firefox add-on RESTer to test the JSON response. Now I want to alter the JSON response to add more key and value programatically. I am sharing all my resources which I have used but nothing changed

[image: This is my view]

This is my JSON response so far:

```
[
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/1\">General discussion</a>",
            "tid": "1",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/2\">Miscellaneous - Hangout forums</a>",
            "tid": "2",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/3\">Debt Management and Debt Consolidation</a>",
            "tid": "3",
            "description": ""
        },
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/6\">Archive</a>",
            "tid": "6",
            "description": ""
        }
```

But I want my JSON like this:

```
[
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/1\">General discussion</a>",
            "tid": "1",
            "description": "",
            "MY_CUSTOM_KEY": "MY CUSTOM VALUE"
        },
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/2\">Miscellaneous - Hangout forums</a>",
            "tid": "2",
            "description": "",
            "MY_CUSTOM_KEY": "MY CUSTOM VALUE"
        },
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/3\">Debt Management and Debt Consolidation</a>",
            "tid": "3",
            "description": "",
            "MY_CUSTOM_KEY": "MY CUSTOM VALUE"
        },
        {
            "Name": "<a href=\"/forum/6\">Archive</a>",
            "tid": "6",
            "description": "",
            "MY_CUSTOM_KEY": "MY CUSTOM VALUE"
        }
]
```

I had used [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) to alter the JSON but couldn't get it:

```
function MY_MODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if($view->name == 'MY_VIEW_NAME') {
        $results = &$view->result;
        foreach($results as $key=>$value) {
            $value->MY_CUSTOM_KEY= "MY CUSTOM VALUE";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach($results as $key => &$value) {
    $value->MY_CUSTOM_KEY= "MY CUSTOM VALUE";
}
```

Comment: not worked this solution

Answer (score 0):

This hook solved my question: [hook_views_post_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_render/8.2.x)

```
function MY_MODULE_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {
    if($view->name == 'MY_VIEW_NAME') {
        $results = &$output;
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $result->MY_CUSTOM_KEY= "MY CUSTOM VALUE";
        }
    }
}
```